# How to fire RowCommand for a GridView which is inside a Repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, repeater, rowcommand

I have a `Repeater` and inside it a `GridView`. Now I want to to fire `GridView`'s RowCommand. So can any one tell me how can it be?

Comment: "A RowCommand is used to capture and process a button click contained within a Row of a GridView.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it sounds like you want to do is handle the [`RowCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) event in each of your `GridView`s.

One way to do this would be to create an event handler for the `ItemCreated` event in the `Repeater` control.  In that event handler, you could then add the `RowCommand` event handler to each `GridView` using `+=` syntax.  So, if your `RowCommand` event handler method is called "GridView1_RowCommand", you could do this:

```
Repeater1_ItemCreated(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

    GridView tempGV = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("GridView1");
    tempGV += GridView1_RowComamnd;

}
```

Then, each time a `RowCommand` event is fired from one of your `GridView`s, the `GridView_RowCommand` event will be called.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [site](http://forums.asp.net/t/1378613.aspx), where a similar discussion is done.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Ok, @BilltheLizard thanks for your suggestion I will follow from now.